# Change in one select menu disables another select menu on webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a `<select>` menu on my page.

I'd like it so if the selectedIndex **doesn't** equal '1' (i.e. **if (this.selectedIndex!=1**)) then it disables (`<select disabled="disabled">`) another `<select>` menu on my web page.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Which part do you have a problem with? Event binding? Finding elements in the DOM? Setting disabled on a DOM element?

Comment: Hi baz. I'm just really not sure where to begin with this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id="first"><option>a</option><option>b</option></select>
<select id="second"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('change', function() {
       if(this.selectedIndex != 1) {
           document.getElementById('second').disabled = true;
       }
       else {
           document.getElementById('second').disabled = false;
       }
    });
</script>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qU5Sc/)

Comment: Just a note: except some marginal cases, you should not use inline event handlers (`onchange="test()"` and the kind).

Comment: @Manuel Removed my downvote. Btw, inside the event handler you can use `this`, so you can save one `getElementById()`.

Comment: @bazmegakapa thnx changed it!

Answer (score 1):

1. bind a `change` event on the first select (`addEventListener()` or for older IE, `attachEvent()`)

   - [MDC on addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)
2. in the event handler, check the `selectedIndex` whether it is 1 or not
3. if it is not 1, find the second select in DOM, and make it disabled (set its `disabled` property to true)

**EDIT**: I created a little Fiddle solving the problem the way I described. I suggest NOT using inline event handlers in your HTML (`onchange="xz()"`), there are far more advanced techniques available, and the HTML should only be the markup, no style and behavior.

So, it is as easy as this:

```
document.getElementById('fos1').addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById('fos2').disabled=this.selectedIndex != 1;
});
```

where `fos1` and `fos2` are the IDs of your select boxes.

- [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CzF3Q/)
- [Early event handlers on QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html)

Comment: Many thanks for this baz. I'm so new to Javascript it's unreal. Spend most of my time in CodeIgniter. Slowly starting to understand. Thanks again for this.

Comment: @mcgarriers I have updated my answer. If you're new to Javascript, please review the things I have written. There are lots of old and outdated techniques.

Comment: Thank you, baz. I've b'marked for later. Many thanks for your explanation and the links.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/rdeww/1/

JQ

```
$('#one').change(function () {
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val();  

    if(selected != 1) {
        $('#two').attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
        $('#two').attr('disabled',false);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="one">
    <option value="1">Dont disable</option>
    <option value="2">Disable</option>
    <option value="3">Disable</option>
    <option value="4">Disable</option>
    <option value="5">Disable</option>
</select>
<select id="two">
    <option value="1">Random select</option>
    <option value="2">Random select</option>
    <option value="3">Random select</option>
    <option value="4">Random select</option>
    <option value="5">Random select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have not seen jQuery mentioned.

Comment: still, it's a valid technique (much more than inline event handlers), but I think the OP is not familiar with jQuery.